# Upgrade to Unity 2018.2.2f1 resulting in missing file errors from Visual Studio

Tags: unity, visual-studio

After being prompted by Unity to upgrade and doing so, Visual Studio is now giving me a long list of errors in the project about missing files.

```
Error   CS2001  Source file 'Packages\com.unity.textmeshpro\Scripts\Runtime\FastAction.cs' could not be found.  Unity.TextMeshPro   C:\Nightmare Games\Games\In Production\H0V3R\CSC    1   Active
Error   CS2001  Source file 'Packages\com.unity.textmeshpro\Scripts\Runtime\MaterialReferenceManager.cs' could not be found.    Unity.TextMeshPro   C:\Nightmare Games\Games\In Production\H0V3R\CSC    1   Active
Error   CS2001  Source file 'Packages\com.unity.textmeshpro\Scripts\Runtime\PackageResourceImporterWindow.cs' could not be found.   Unity.TextMeshPro   C:\Nightmare Games\Games\In Production\H0V3R\CSC    1   Active
```

There are 45 of these, and they're all in the project Unity.TextMeshPro.  I've looked for these files and they don't see to be anywhere on my PC.  Should I try reinstalling Unity or starting a new project again?  Has anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I did have all 45 files, but they were nowhere near the project folder VS was trying to find them in.  They were in

```
C:\Users\(me)\AppData\Local\Unity\cache\packages\packages.unity.com\com.unity.textmeshpro@1.2.4\Scripts\Runtime.
```

I copied them over and everything seems fine now.  I expect Unity to handle this kind of stuff on its own when I run the installer.

Comment: Thanks, I created a symbolic link to the folder in a path consistent with this.
But the odd thing was I had made a new project prior to updating unity and it had auto included/added the TextMeshPro package.

Thinking that I don't want it in my project at this point I went to Window Packages and removed it. Turns out there was an update to TextMeshPro I wonder if that would have resolved this issue.